# Dont want to uninstall my module in openerp

Tags: odoo

My requirement is that if anyone install my module in openerp gtk-client after that he/she can't uninstall that module in current database.Consider database name as 'XYZ'.

Answer (score 1):

I found a solution by inheriting the `ir.module.module` class and overriding the `button_uninstall` method.

Answer (score 0):

To uninstall a module, you can go to Administration / Modules / Modules... search and open your module.

Then, there is a "uninstall" button to uninstall your module. However, it's a Beta version of the functionnality. I've never had a problem yet.

EDIT:

According to your comment, the only way to do that is to specify a security file to prevent a user can go into the administration menu.

Comment: Bt I dont want to uninstall my module.Take in mind that anyone can install my module but cant uninstall it even if he/she wants.

Answer (score 0):

As I recall, the [use control](http://bazaar.launchpad.net/~openerp-commiter/openobject-addons/stable_5.0-extra-addons/files/3609/use_control/) module could not be uninstalled. There was a big discussion about it in [this bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/openobject-server/+bug/506662), and it's since been removed from the extra addons branch. You could poke around in the source code to figure out what it was doing to be so nasty.

Answer (score 0):

Not quite what you asked, but you could maybe configure `__openerp__.py` to:

- set you module in the `Hidden` category
- set `auto_install` to True

In this way, you are guaranteed that your module will be installed, and not uninstallable.